# How can I expand a collapsible section with csjs or ssjs?

Tags: xpages

I have several sections on an xPage.

How can I expand a collapsible section with csjs or ssjs?

Can I expand / collapse all at once?   Can I do them individually?

How can I expand / collapse a  collapsible section with csjs or ssjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your name of section is `section1` you can expand/collapse a particular section by using following SSJS code:

```
getComponent("section1").setClosed(boolean);
```

Comment: I'm sure you are all getting tired of answering my questions.  Where can I find this information myself?  How did you know about this function?   Where is it documented?

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into [XPages API Inspector](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20API%20Inspector). Another trick is if I need to find the methods/properties of particular control I write `getComponent("section1").getClass().getName();`. This gives me the class name which in this case is `com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspSection`. So now I simply write code as `var s:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspSection = getComponent("section1");` and typing `s.` will show you content assist.

Comment: Also, go to the Package Explorer view, open the relevant Java file for your XPages under the local\xsp folder. Find the relevant class for the component you want to inspect and press F4. Check out the NotesIn9 video I did on F4 is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

To set all expanded/collapsed at the same time, compute the property to a viewScope variable, then toggle the viewScope property. It's a technique I've used before.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, I believe it's a bit of an overkill using SSJS for this simple task with full or partial refresh. It's simpler to use client-side JS. 
With JQuery, this is the code you could use and attach it to a click event:

`x$("#{id:section1}").show();
x$("#{id:section1}").hide();`